# On the reliability of validation loss as a metric

Tags: neural-networks, validation

I have the following plot of the training and validation loss from a deep neural network. The signature U-curve of the validation loss can be noticed. I want to use the validation loss as the metric for saving the weights of my model and I am currently using the weights with the **lowest** possible validation loss. However, a question came to me, suppose I list down the top 5 weights with the following losses:

1. Epoch 120:  1.62
2. Epoch 150:  1.65
3. Epoch 190:  1.68
4. Epoch 230:  1.73
5. Epoch 270:  1.78

As you can see, their losses are very near each other while the best validation loss occurs the earliest epoch. Particularly, how can I quantify which is better than Top 1 and 2 when their losses varies only by less than 0.03?

I am using data augmentation and I think that the generalizability would be better when trained for longer epochs, however the validation loss does not select Top 3 for example when its difference between the Top 1 is quite small.

Any suggestions will do, thank you.

[image: Graph]